# Export content of HTML Table to Excel Sheet so as to be supported by browsers like IE , Mozilla , Firefox etc.?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, excel

Here is my HTML Page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Table </title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
</script>

</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Header 1</th>
<th>Header 2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>

<input id ="export" type = "button" value = "Export"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Now i want the user to export the content on web page into excel sheet. How can i do that ?
I dont want to go with javascript because in that case the code will be browser - dependent ?

Any Advice !
Thanks in Advance.

P.N. : I have come across few question in stackoverflow which says use of jQuery can be a good option. But the problem is i have zero knowledge of jQuery .

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use my code to export html file to excel file. In this case, I created your above sample and just copy and paste my code in html file, then you'll see the result and you'll be able to download excel file.

use above java code in first then put this following html code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('testTable', 'W3C Example Table')" value="Export to Excel">
<table class="tableizer-table" id="testTable" summary="Code page support in different versions of MS Windows." rules="groups" 
frame="hsides" border="2">
<tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Header 1</th><th>Header 2</th></tr>
 <tr><td>row 1, cell 1</td><td>row 1, cell 2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>row 2, cell 1</td><td>row 2, cell 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I get the following error  Webpage error details

`User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Thu, 29 Aug 2013 07:31:24 UTC


Message: Unterminated string constant
Line: 10
Char: 119
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/592635/Desktop/table.html


Message: Object expected
Line: 28
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/592635/Desktop/table.html`

Comment: Its ok, you can check your html through this link: (http://behdasht.co/wp/test.php)

Answer (score -1):

use this following java code to export Html to Excel:

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
, template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]
><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}
</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbo
ok></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
, base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
, format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
return function(table, name) {
if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
 window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
  }
})()
```

Comment: Is it a java code ? Thats jQuery man i have come across it but dont know how to use it!